#  Mapkit - Change annotation image on tapping

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

I am new to iphone development. I have added annotations on the map. I am able to catch the tapping event on the annotation in didSelectAnnotationView(). But i want to change the image of the annotation when the user taps on it.

Answer (score 4):

Set the image property, as such.

```
annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationIcon.png"];
```

EDIT

So, you seems to be using [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
which has a `pinColor` property.

Therefore, you can change it as such

```
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; // green and purple are 2 other colors.
```

Comment: The annotation image is changed when i click  on the annotation but i want to reset the image to green when i click on the selected pole again. Is there a way to implement this? The annotations which are clicked only once should remain in red color.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:
I'll assume you are using this function already for custom MKAnnotation views

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {...}
```

and I'll update @djibouti33 answer from Objective-c to Swift 3:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        view.image = UIImage(named: "unselected_marker")
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)//keep the new icon size resobable.
     }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        view.image = UIImage(named: "selected_marker")
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an `MKAnnotationView` and not `MKPinAnnotationView` you can just rely on `MKMapViewDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image"];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected_image"];
}
```